# Вид содержимого файла при загрузке

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет.
Есть код загрузки файла csv

```
  <?php

    include "connection.php";
    $deleterecords = "TRUNCATE TABLE elitprice";
    mysql_query($deleterecords);

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
            echo "<h2>" . "Файл ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." загружается. Дождитесь окончания!" . "</h2>";
            echo "<h2>Содержимое:</h2>";
            echo "<div style='height: 260px;overflow-y: scroll;'>";     
                readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
            echo "</div>";
        }

        $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
            $import="INSERT into elitprice(article,alt_name,brand,price,day,aviable,supplier,currency) values('$data[0]', '$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]')";

        mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
            mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
        }

        fclose($handle);

        print "<span style='color:green;font-weight: 700;padding:20px;'>Прайс загружен!</span></br><a href='#'>Перейти к редактированию</a>";

    }
  ?>
```

Как править вид выводимого содержимого?

```
readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
```

на данный момент все записи и разделители идут в одно строку
как структурировать не соображу никак.

сейчас выводит так:

сейчас выводит так:

`0 130 063 514;BOSCH;Ел. двиг. пост. току;998.02;1;1-2;UAH;E01 0 130 111 032;BOSCH;Електродвигун постійного струм;1318.20;1;1-2;UAH;E01 0 130 111 042;BOSCH;Мотор вентилятора салону;1038.61;1;1-2;UAH;E01 0 204 054 486;BOSCH;Головний гальмiвний цилiндр;3207.36;1;1-2;UAH;E01 0 204 054 628;BOSCH;Головний гальмiвний цилiндр;2005.32;1;1-2;UAH;E01 0 221 503 033;BOSCH;Котушка запалювання;1729.31;1;1-2;UAH;E01 0 232 101 027;BOSCH;Датчик фази;1637.14;1;1-2;UAH;E01 0 242 050 502;BOSCH;Свічка usr4ac;60.36;1;1-2;UAH;E01 0 242 135 802;BOSCH;Свічка yr 7 dc+;221.46;1;1-2;UAH;E01 0 092 M4F 340;BOSCH;Мотоакумулятор BOSCH-M4F34;902.08;1;1-2;UAH;E01 0 092 M4F 410;BOSCH;Мотоакумулятор BOSCH-M4F41;1252.59;1;1-2;UAH;E01 0 130 111 012;BOSCH;Електродвигун постійного струм;1141.39;1;1-2;UAH;E01 0 130 111 116;BOSCH;Мотор вентилятора салону;1181.56;1;1-2;UAH;E01 0 130 111 189;BOSCH;Ел. двиг. пост. току;1280.46;1;1-2;UAH;E01 0 130 303 243;BOSCH;Вентилятор охолодження;1732.36;1;1-2;UAH;E0`

как сделать например, чтобы каждая строка таблицы excel шла с новой строки

```
0 130 063 514;BOSCH;Ел. двиг. пост. току;998.02;1;1-2;UAH;E01 
0 130 111 032;BOSCH;Електродвигун постійного струм;1318.20;1;1-2;UAH;E01 
0 130 111 042;BOSCH;Мотор вентилятора салону;1038.61;1;1-2;UAH;E01 
0 204 054 486;BOSCH;Головний гальмiвний цилiндр;3207.36;1;1-2;UAH;E01 
0 204 054 628;BOSCH;Головний гальмiвний цилiндр;2005.32;1;1-2;UAH;E01 
0 221 503 033;BOSCH;Котушка запалювання;1729.31;1;1-2;UAH;E01 
0 232 101 027;BOSCH;Датчик фази;1637.14;1;1-2;UAH;E01 
0 242 050 502;BOSCH;Свічка usr4ac;60.36;1;1-2;UAH;E01
```

возможно ли скрыть разделитель ";" или вывести в виде таблицы

Comment: уточните, что вы имеете в виду под "править содержимое", что выводится сейчас, чего хотите добиться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте перед выводом файла:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

Или оберните вывод в HTML тег `<pre/>`